# Delphi DirectX Component Installation

Tags: delphi, directx, delphi-xe2

I have downloaded one DirectX Animation Project from a forum.
When I am trying to load the project in Delphi XE2 I am getting one error message:

> “Class TDXDraw” and ” Class TDXDDIB” not found.

Then I load the project ignoring the error message. Again I am getting error message for the following component like “DXDraw1: TDXDraw”, “DXDIB1: TDXDIB” and “Background: TDXDIB”. Hence I have downloaded “DXSDK_Jun10.exe” and installed. But the error is the same.

I think, the error occurs due the DirectX components are not imported in DelphiXE2.

Which components are to be imported and how?

Comment: It's somehow like you said; you need to find out what components from what package(s) the project you are talking about uses. Then you have to install those components into your Delphi IDE and after that open the project.

Answer (score 1):

Those look like (un)DelphiX component names.  Take a look at http://www.micrel.cz/Dx/index.html for DelphiXE2 support.